# How to check address (domain, port, schema) of client that called the resource in restlet framework?

Tags: restlet

In Restlet framework, I'm trying to check if request to resource comes from specific IP address.

So far, I was not able to find this information.

In resource code, I've looked in whole getRequest() and getRequest().getClientInfo() content, but did not success.
In resource code:

```
ClientInfo info = getRequest().getClientInfo();
// this code returns the address (if set) but no port, no schema
// i was also not able to undesrtand, which address means exactly what
logger.info("addr: "+info.getAddress());
logger.info("fwd: "+getClientInfo().getForwardedAddresses());
logger.info("upstream: "+getClientInfo().getUpstreamAddress());

// this returns some strange number, definitely not the port of the caller
logger.info("port: "+info.getPort());
```

When i execute request from client running at http://localhost:9996/test,  in resource log i get the following lines:

```
addr: 127.0.0.1 
fwd: []
upstream: 127.0.0.1 
port: 57275
```

I have also tried to set:

```
server.getContext().getParameters().add("useForwardedForHeader", "true");
```

.. no change

I have also tried to list the request headers, no suitable information inside.

Please, do you have any suggestions, how to get the caller IP (schema, domain, port)?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me using Restlet 2.0 with Java 6:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param request
 * @return
 */
public static String getBasePath(org.restlet.Request request){
    org.restlet.data.Reference rootRef = request.getRootRef();
    org.restlet.data.Reference hostRef = request.getHostRef();
    int hostPort = hostRef.getHostPort();
    return (    rootRef.getScheme()
                + "://"
                + hostRef.getHostDomain()
                + ( ( hostPort==-1 ) ? "" : (":" + hostPort) )
                + rootRef.getPath()
                + "/"
            )
    ;
}
```

If you see the code, it uses `org.restlet.Request.getRootRef()`, `org.restlet.Request.getHoatRef()`, `org.restlet.data.Reference..getHostDomain()`, `org.restlet.data.Reference.getScheme()`, `org.restlet.data.Reference.getPath()`, and `org.restlet.data.Reference..getHostPort()`

If this does not work then please update your question.

Edit:(After 1st comment)
There are some more functions in `org.restlet.Request` that may be useful in such cases. They are:

1. Reference `getOriginalRef()` Returns the original reference as requested by the client.
2. Reference `getReferrerRef()` Returns the referrer reference if available.
3. Reference `getResourceRef()` Returns the reference of the target resource.

Edit 2: Code to read request headers.

```
/**
 * This method return the HTTP headers as an object of Restlet Form
 * @param serverResource
 * @return
 */
public static org.restlet.data.Form getRequestHeaders(org.restlet.resource.ServerResource serverResource)
{   return (org.restlet.data.Form) serverResource.getRequestAttributes().get(org.restlet.engine.http.header.HeaderConstants.ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS);
}
```

Code to read headers using above function.

```
public class MyResource extends ServerResource
{
.
.
@Get/Post/...
public Object/void myFunc(Arguments...)
{
    Form headers = RestletUtil.getRequestHeaders(this);
    boolean ignoreCase = true ;
    // Note: 'Host' header is in HTTP/1.1
    String stringHostHeader = headers.getFirstValue("Host", ignoreCase);
    System.out.println("value of 'Host' header is: " + stringHostHeader);
    .
    .
```

Tell us what result are you getting.

Edit 3:
So far this answer assumed that the server application wants to read that "How the client sees the server." However the comments section reveals that in this case the server application wants to know that what is the alphanumeric name of client, and port number of a web application running on client machine.

Comment: Thank you for answer. This method returns the schema://domain:port for resource called in restlet server. What i need is the schema://domain:port of the caller of this resource.

Comment: @PeterKostelnik If you look at this link, https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/javadocs/2.1/jse/api/org/restlet/Request.html , then you will find a method named `getOriginalRef()`. Try replacing `getRootRef()` with `getOriginalRef()`. You may get what you want.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work (i've tried lot of these things before, thats why i was forced to come here :) ) root/original/referrer/host/resource ref, that all points to the address of resource at server. not the caller :/

Comment: Please look into contents of file `C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts` (On Windows) or `/etc/hosts` (On Linux), on your client computer. If it has an entry that looks like: `127.0.0.1 localhost`, then comment it using `#`. If this does not work, and your requests are HTTP/1.1 requests, then read the headers at the server side. I am editing my answer in some time, to include code-to-read-headers.

Comment: Of course, I've tried also to check the headers. I think, i've checked most likely everything available in ServerResource. The host in headers is address:port of restlet resource (this time no schema), not the address client, who requested resource. :/

So far, i was able to get client address via:

    getClientInfo().getAddress();

But there is no schema, no port (port looks like randomly generated number, as it changes per each different request).

Maybe bug/issue in restlet framework?

Comment: @PeterKostelnik Is your client also a web application? I mean an HTTP server or deployed on an HTTP server? Also about the client port number looking like a random number: When a client sends a request to the server, it tells the server that it is waiting for a response on a particular port number. That port number is generated by the client program on the fly. Thats all for that random client port number. Now coming on other issues: If the client is sending request to server, then the server side server sends a response back to it using client's IP address and...(continued in next comment)

Comment: ... port number. If the client is sending request through a proxy server, then the client request contains more than 1 IP addresses, which is a chain, contained in the header named as `X-Forwarded-For`. `X-Forwarded-For` is a defacto header, i.e. A header used by industry as a convention, but there is no formal doc for it by W3C(The last time i checked the specs was 2016). So the client address is always an IP address. In case you want the client's address-port to look like "localhost:7070" or "xyz.com:6767", then you have to put a web application on "localhost:7070" or "xyz.com:6767" ...Cont

Comment: Continued... and then add your custom header/query/path parameter informing the server about it. That custom header should a part of specification/documentation of the server application.

Comment: the client is also restlet service, so it for sure runs on concrete schema://ip:port. X-Forwarded-For header contains only client's address. No schema, no port.

Comment: Your server application can not know whether the client's computer has an application running on schema://client-ip:client-port unless you do one of these: 1.Pass a header/parameter through the client program and program the server to make use of it. 2.keep a list of configuration/database-entries which keeps a record like client-ip&port as name and client-web-app-address&client-web-app-port as values.

Comment: Also: In case your client computer has an alphanumeric name like "my-local-computer.our-local-LAN" (This is not a name that a conventional website name that you enter in browser address bar), then one of the DNS servers MUST have an entry that reads "proper-ip-address my-local-computer.our-local-LAN" in it's hosts file.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Unfortunately, none of above is the solution.  I'll try another approach.